# JUnit/Ant XML file format for stdout

Tags: ant, junit, hudson

I'm writing my own test program and I want to be able to re-use tools like Hudson for displaying the results of the test cases. I've so far gotten the results of the text file all into the same XML file and with success, failure, and errors.

Now I want to add the output of the test into the file. I have it set up so I can get the output of a test for each test individually, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it into the XML file in a way Hudson will recognize.

I want to do something like this...

```
<testsuite>
  <testcase>
    <success classname="...">
      <stdout>
        This is standard output
      </stdout>
    </success>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

But this doesn't get recognized. I see in the Ant source code that it's defined as "system-out", but I also see that it seems it wants the file in this format.

```
<testsuite>
  <testcase classname="..." />
  <system-out>
    This is standard output
  </system-out>
</testsuite>
```

Is there anyway to make this file so that I can have a specific stdout for each test case? Or do I have to make a new testsuite for every test case?

Edit: I seem to be able to get this format to work, but I'm still disappointed that I can't print the output during a success. I'd like it it while browsing tests, someone could see the output of that test.

```
<testsuite>
  <testcase name="...">
    <failure message="shows up as error message">
      standard out (shows up as stacktrace)
    </failure>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Is there anywhere that shows what format Hudson accepts? I feel bad commiting bad revisions to source control just to get it to run on the automated build server.

I also can't seem to find where inside of Hudson the code for this functionality is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can not use the "success".

Code for this functionality is https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/junit/CaseResult.java